# how can I achieve loop indexing in recursive laravel components?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-blade

I am stuck in a problem and tried so many things but all invain.
actually what i want is to achieve incrementive indexing in recursive laravel components.
like for example i want the indexing to be
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ...... so on.

my code is,

```
@foreach($costs as $cost)
   <x-estimation-item :cost="$cost" />
@endforeach
```

and my component is,

```
@props([
    'cost',
])

<div>
    @foreach($cost->children as $child)
        <x-estimation-item :cost="$child" />
    @endforeach
</div>
```

I am  using Laravel Adjacency List package and my levels are upto 9 levels.
Now I just want to increment value each time the components calls.
i will access that incremented value above the foreach loop of childrens.
Any idea how I can achieve this ?

Any Idea or piece of code if possible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your `EstimationItem` component accept a counter prop.

`App\View\Components\EstimationItem`

```php
<?php

namespace App\View\Components;

use Illuminate\View\Component;

class EstimationItem extends Component
{
    public $cost;
    public $counter;

    public function __construct($cost, $counter) {
        $this->cost = $cost;
        $this->counter = $counter;
        $counter->increment();
    }
}
```

`resources/views/components/estimation-item.blade.php`

```
@props([
    'cost',
    'counter'
])

<div>
    @foreach($cost->children as $child)
        {{ $counter->getValue() }}
        <x-estimation-item :cost="$child" :counter="$counter" />
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Declare a `Counter` class to container the index and increment it each time a component is rendered.

`App\Pojos\Counter`

```php
namespace App\Pojos;

final class Counter {
    private int index;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->index = 0;
    }

    public function increment() {
        $this->index++;
    }

    public function getValue(): int {
        return $this->index;
    }
}
```

Initialize the counter and pass it down as prop to your component.

```
@php
$counter = new \App\Pojo\Counter();
@endphp

@foreach($costs as $cost)
   {{ $counter->getValue() }}
   <x-estimation-item :cost="$cost" :counter="$counter" />
@endforeach
```

You can see this in [action here in the playground](https://laravelplayground.com/#/snippets/6e7b2a22-748b-4643-ace7-850dd0c3b973).